# Cell fracture causing additional non desirable geometry. How to fix?

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on

I'm trying to use Cell Fracture addon to 'break' simple building model but it causes additional geometry which makes model very ugly.
Original model:
[image: Original model]

After Cell Fracture:
[image: After Cell Fracture]

I understand it is something wrong with my model because other models I tried works well. But what exactly wrong with it? I applyed location, rotation and scale but it not helps at all. I also tried to triangulate the model (previously it helped me to resolve UV unwrapping issues) but it also not helps. The .blend file is uploaded [here](https://yadi.sk/d/2dGnOiqfcakCy).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is usually caused by a failed boolean operation. Do you have any non-manifold or self-intersecting geometry? (I wasn't able to download the .blend for some reason..)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes, the model have non manfold elements on the roof. Unfortunately I can't fix it right now and check but seems it is the reason why Cell fracture works unexpected. Thank you for your help.